# How to use Apache Logger or Log4J in Coldfusion MX

Tags: coldfusion

Is there any source available which shows how may I use Logging functions in ColdFusion?

Or is there any Logger available in ColdFusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can use Log4j but whey don't you try Logbox (http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/LogBox.cfm). I had tried with coldbox framework but work without  framework as well.

Comment: Here is download link http://www.coldbox.org/download/logbox 
And it is inspired from log4j :)

Comment: If you'd prefer not to implement a framework, CF has built in logging with cflog.  It's great to log silent functions output.  Ray Camden wrote a good blog on how he uses it in his development and debugging :[http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/10/4/Another-CFLOGJSON-Tip](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/10/4/Another-CFLOGJSON-Tip)